# How to get data out of the notifications?[Error retrieving data] laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-notification, laravel-5.8

When ever a user post on a thread its send an notifications and then form the navagition bar there is an drop down menu where the user can see all his notifications, but when I try to open it it gives an error

> Undefined index: thread (View:
>   C:\Users\Merlijn\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Laravel
>   Projects\Forum\resources\views\layouts\partials\notification\replied_to_thread.blade.php)
>   (View: C:\Users\Merlijn\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Laravel
>   Projects\Forum\resources\views\layouts\partials\notification\replied_to_thread.blade.php)
>   (View: C:\Users\Merlijn\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Laravel
>   Projects\Forum\resources\views\layouts\partials\notification\replied_to_thread.blade.php)
>   (View: C:\Users\Merlijn\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Laravel
>   Projects\Forum\resources\views\layouts\partials\notification\replied_to_thread.blade.php)

while if I do an `dd($notification)` i get this data

```
#attributes: array:8 [▼
"id" => "c055bf7e-8aa0-41d6-b188-d73073dbfefb"
"type" => "App\Notifications\RepliedToThread"
"notifiable_type" => "App\User"
"notifiable_id" => 1
"data" => "{"thread":{"id":2,"subject":"22JSUpdated Updated Updated","thread":"eaweaewarea kejwabnejk.wabe;beh;lkwabhel.kwajewaeaweawe","type":"Question Updated","created_ ▶"
"read_at" => null
"created_at" => "2019-03-19 13:28:11"
"updated_at" => "2019-03-19 13:28:11"
]
#original: array:8 [▼
"id" => "c055bf7e-8aa0-41d6-b188-d73073dbfefb"
"type" => "App\Notifications\RepliedToThread"
"notifiable_type" => "App\User"
"notifiable_id" => 1
"data" => "{"thread":{"id":2,"subject":"22JSUpdated Updated Updated","thread":"eaweaewarea kejwabnejk.wabe;beh;lkwabhel.kwajewaeaweawe","type":"Question Updated","created_ ▶"
"read_at" => null
"created_at" => "2019-03-19 13:28:11"
"updated_at" => "2019-03-19 13:28:11"
]
```

and in the navbar I am trying to access the notification data like this

```
@foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
<a href="{{route('thread.show',$notification->data['thread']['id'])}}">

    {{$notification->data['user']['name']}} commented on <strong> 
{{$notification->data['thread']['subject']}}</strong>
</a>
@endforeach
```

but its says `['thread']['id']` is undefined while in the `dd` I can see that in the `array:8 is

```
"data" => "{"thread":{"id":2,"subject":"22JSUpdated Updated Updated","thread":"eaweaewarea kejwabnejk.wabe;beh;lkwabhel.kwajewaeaweawe","type":"Question Updated","created_at":"2019-03-19 10:56:58","updated_at":"2019-03-19 10:56:58","user_id":1,"solution":null},"user":{"id":1,"name":"johndoe","email":"johndoe@example.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2019-03-14 15:34:15","updated_at":"2019-03-14 15:34:15"}}
```

but why can I not find the id of the thread an says its undefined instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` is a string containing a json format. If you don't tell PHP this information, PHP will just interpret this as a string, which has no keys.

So, you will have to parse the json before using the keys:

```
$data = json_decode($notification->data);
echo $data->thread->id;
```

---

**Update:** I supose you are getting these values using Eloquent? If so, you can [let eloquent parse these json strings for you](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting).

Just define a `$casts` property on your model and add the property.

```
protected $casts = [
    'data' => 'array',
];
```

Now you can use the property directly: `$notification->data['thread']['id']`

Comment: is it also possible to do this in the view? in anyway

Comment: `protected $casts = [
    'data' => 'array',
];` after adding that to the `App\Notifications\RepliedToThread.php` its still says its undefined in both the thread and the user. note The notification maps was made with `php artisan make:notification RepliedToThread
` so its out of a `model`

Comment: You should add the `$cast` property to your model, not the notification.

Comment: Yes this answer solves my problem, I was looping my notifications in the vue.js component and my data was not formatted before I was doing JSON.parse to get data objects values. after reading this answer I added  casts variable and add data =>  'json' new its formated  for me